# Install python modules in heroku while using python-shell not working

Tags: python, node.js, express, heroku

I'm trying to import a python file into node web application. On my local machine it works fine, but when I upload it to heroku, the modules don't get imported correctly, and I get an error message saying, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'`.

I'm assuming that the modules are not installed. So I made a requirements.txt file, and imported in python like this:

```
import subprocess
import sys
subprocess.call([sys.executable, "-r", "pip3", "install", 'requirements.txt'])
```

I still get the previous error of: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'`. How can I install python modules in heroku while using python-shell?

**Python Imports**

```
import json
import pickle
import random
import tensorflow as tf
import tflearn
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()
```

**Node**

```
const options = {
    pythonOptions: ['-u'],
    pythonPath: 'python3'
};
let pyshell = new PythonShell('./python_2/script.py', options);
```

Here's the full output error I'm receiving:

```
2019-09-02T19:11:03.182951+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:174
2019-09-02T19:11:03.182964+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2019-09-02T19:11:03.182967+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-09-02T19:11:03.182969+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-09-02T19:11:03.182971+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
2019-09-02T19:11:03.182973+00:00 app[web.1]: at PythonShell.parseError (/app/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:260:21)
2019-09-02T19:11:03.182975+00:00 app[web.1]: at terminateIfNeeded (/app/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:139:32)
2019-09-02T19:11:03.182978+00:00 app[web.1]: at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:131:13)
2019-09-02T19:11:03.182980+00:00 app[web.1]: at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
2019-09-02T19:11:03.182983+00:00 app[web.1]: at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
2019-09-02T19:11:03.182985+00:00 app[web.1]: ----- Python Traceback -----
2019-09-02T19:11:03.182987+00:00 app[web.1]: File "python_2/model.py", line 5, in <module>
2019-09-02T19:11:03.182989+00:00 app[web.1]: import tensorflow as tf
2019-09-02T19:11:03.182991+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event at:
2019-09-02T19:11:03.182994+00:00 app[web.1]: at terminateIfNeeded (/app/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:153:26)
2019-09-02T19:11:03.182996+00:00 app[web.1]: at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:131:13)
2019-09-02T19:11:03.182998+00:00 app[web.1]: at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
2019-09-02T19:11:03.183000+00:00 app[web.1]: at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
2019-09-02T19:11:03.224746+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-09-02T19:11:03.225516+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-09-02T19:11:03.230041+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! backend@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
2019-09-02T19:11:03.230381+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-09-02T19:11:03.230929+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-09-02T19:11:03.232455+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.0.0 start script.
2019-09-02T19:11:03.233317+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-09-02T19:11:03.270676+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-09-02T19:11:03.272904+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-09-02T19:11:03.273603+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-09-02T19_11_03_247Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Why are you trying to install dependencies at runtime? This should be done at build time.

Comment: That's a good point. What I planned on doing, was installing them, then removing that line that installs it.

Comment: What's the proper way to do it?

Comment: You already have a `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`, right? You'd need one or the other to get Python on Heroku. Just add your dependency there.

Comment: @Chris I have a `requirements.txt` file, and it still didn't work. What's the correct path to insert the `requirements.txt`? It's currently at: `backend/python_2/requirements.txt`

Comment: It needs to be in the root directory of your project.

Comment: @Chris it's still not working... I just added a runtime.txt file inserting: Python-3.6.5 but I'm still getting the error

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the Python portion of your deploy output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198843/discussion-between-jessica-and-chris).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've already configured multiple buildpacks for your app, which if you've got both `node` and `python` you likely have, you should be able to simply add `tensorflow` to your existing `requirements.txt` file to have it installed during deployment.

That file should be in the root directory of your application, beside your `package.json`.

> I just added a runtime.txt file inserting: Python-3.6.5 but I'm still getting the error

Your `runtime.txt` should also be in the root directory of your project, and your requested Python version should be all lowercase, e.g.

```
python-3.6.5
```